# Test private static method throws MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, privateobject.invoke

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private static int GetMonthsDateDiff(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
   {
     // implementatio
   }
}
```

Now I am implementing unit test for it. 
Since the method is private, I have following code:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
PrivateObject testObj = new PrivateObject(myClass);
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 17);
object[] args = new object[2] { fromDate, toDate };
int res = (int)testObj.Invoke("GetMonthsDateDiff", args); //<- exception
```

*An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Attempted to access a missing member.*

What Am I doing wrong? The method exists..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a static method, so use `PrivateType` instead of `PrivatObject` to access it.

See [PrivateType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privatetype.aspx).

Comment: And `InvokeStatic()` instead of `Invoke()` to call it.

Answer (score 11):

Use below code with PrivateType

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
PrivateType testObj = new PrivateType(myClass.GetType());
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 17);
object[] args = new object[2] { fromDate, toDate };
(int)testObj.InvokeStatic("GetMonthsDateDiff", args)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Invoke` method is the one that cannot be found. The `Object` class does not have an `Invoke` method. I think you might be trying to use [this `Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is part of `System.Reflection`.

You can use it like this,

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
var fromDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
var toDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 17);
var args = new object[2] { fromDate, toDate };

var type = myClass.GetType();
// Because the method is `static` you use BindingFlags.Static 
// otherwise, you would use BindingFlags.Instance 
var getMonthsDateDiffMethod = type.GetMethod(
    "GetMonthsDateDiff",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var res = (int)getMonthsDateDiffMethod.Invoke(myClass, args);
```

**However**, you should not be trying to test a `private` method; it is much too specific and subject to change. You should instead make it `public` of a `DateCalculator` class which is private in `MyClass`, or perhaps, making it `internal`, so you can only use inside your assembly.

Answer (score 1):

```
int res = (int)typeof(MyClass).InvokeMember(
                name: "GetMonthsDateDiff", 
                invokeAttr: BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            BindingFlags.Static |
                            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                binder: null, 
                target: null, 
                args: args);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
PrivateObject testObj = new PrivateObject(myClass);
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2015, 3, 17);
object[] args = new object[2] { fromDate, toDate };

//The extra flags
 BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.NonPublic
int res = (int)testObj.Invoke("GetMonthsDateDiff",flags, args);
```